# Can I stuff all things in my Object ? In Javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance

I am writing something like this :

```
Object.prototype.xhr = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : \
                       new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
```

Then, if I do something like `var something = new function(){}`,  `something.xhr.open();`. Well, this works. Likewise, I wish I could stuff all the common things in Object, and use them with any object created in the code. I wish to keep availability of the functionality with any object.

My doubt here is will there be memory overhead like all things created for every object created or will there be one copy of all things and they will be used only when they are called by some object ?

Comment: Why, exactly, do those things need to be on `Object.prototype`?! This looks like taking the problems with global variables and turning them up to eleven. Instead of having one cluttered namespace you clutter the namespace of every single object. What's the advantage over just using globals? (Or a `function openXhrRequest() { … }`?)

Comment: Also, to answer you directly: Only objects you actually create will take up memory, i.e. one object will be created for every `new` *executed*. Javascript objects aren't created by deep-cloning their prototypes, new objects will only have a reference to the original XHR.

Comment: which means no memory load ...?

Comment: Please ignore the practice whether is best or not. All I wish is I should not remember which object is having which things beyond what could be guessed on seeing their names. In true terms, I would like to transfer the clutter from my brain to the browser. Well, if this is not deeply cloned thing, I believe I can go ahead with this approach. (Unless someone shows me any clear answer as why shouldn't I).

Comment: I don't suppose "the person to maintain the code after you will put a hit out on you" counts?